# Can I use a view.getContext() inside the ViewModel as my Databinding class

Tags: android, mvvm, onclicklistener, android-databinding

I am using data binding and MVVM structure.

```
<layout >
  <data>
    <variable
      name="loginVM"
      type="drish.com.dsfaallstars.login.viewmodel.LoginViewModel"/>
  </data>
...
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@{loginVM.buttonText}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:onClick="@{(view)->loginVM.loginProcess(view,username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString())}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19"/>
...
</layout>
```

In my ViewModel I am handling the onClick and in that method I need to show alert box in case of some requirements, the alertbox needs context of view, not the application context.

So is it Ok to let it be this way or should I follow any other approach that will be more effective and helpful.

```
public void loginProcess(View v, String user, String pass) {
    Log.e(LogConst.TAG, "loginProcess: ");
    Log.e(LogConst.TAG, " username " + user + "======= password " + pass);
    if (user.length() < 1 || pass.length() < 1) {
      new CustomLoginDialog(user, pass, v.getContext());
    } else if (checkCredentialsOffline(user, pass)) {
      Log.e(LogConst.TAG, "loginProcess: Async ");
      new LoginTaskAsync(v, user, pass).execute();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the main purposes of using MVVM is to make your app testable. Ideally, the ViewModel should abstract away all android-specific dependencies so that you can write non-instrumentation tests for its business logic. I created an "Activity" interface behind which I put most context-specific calls (such as "showDialog") so that I could mock them when needed.

Comment: " I created an "Activity" interface ", can you please elaborate... like do you create an java "interface" or something else. I am sure I am missing what you said.

Comment: I created a Java interface, `IActivity` and I made it a parameter to my ViewModel's constructor. You can use Dagger for dependency injection as well. This way, you can mock something like `IActivity.displayDialog` in unit tests just to confirm a certain message was displayed under certain conditions without having the test pause for user input (in fact, it would throw exceptions if you tried to do this in a unit (non-instrumentation) test.  Let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "Yes." However, you may want to split up your view model into two different classes: one for data and one for handling events.

It is common to need event handlers with data binding and I prefer to have those event handlers in a separate class separate from the data. You just end up passing two values to the binding class instead of one. If that bothers you, then stick with the one view model class you have now.

Comment: "You just end up passing two values to the binding class instead of one" means using binding.setXXX(viewmodel) one for event and one for data.

Comment: Yes. You have a `binding.setModel(viewModel)` and a `binding.setHandlers(handlers)`.